# AES-CBC pre-determined IV vs. null IV

Tags: aes, cbc, initialization-vector, copy-protection

Is there any security advantage to using a pre-determined IV in CBC mode over a null IV? I'm implementing a license key system similar to [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16465/Product-Keys-Based-on-the-Advanced-Encryption-Stan), but I'm confused by the authors use of a pre-determined IV embedded in the client code alongside the key. Presumably a properly randomized IV wasn't used because the resulting license key would be too long, but wouldn't a null IV be just as (in)secure?

Comment: You are right: There is nothing special about the zero IV (assuming AES is secure); it is just as bad as any other fixed IV.

Comment: Note that symmetric crypto means that key generators are possible. Using asymmetric keys only cracks but not key generators are possible, but they produce longer product keys.

Comment: In my case the target is an embedded system, so the symmetric key will be fairly secure in the inaccessible firmware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no practical difference between zero IV and any other constant IV here.

With some older ciphers that have a small enough keyspace (or weaknesses that allow reducing it) you could have a [rainbow table](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18307/rainbow-table-for-des-with-all-zero-plaintext) for the encryption of the zero vector which might make zero IV a weaker choice in some cases, but that would be impossible for AES with its 128-256 bit keys.

Note that when a key is only used to encrypt a single plaintext, a constant IV is secure.